# Can I view a diagram of my running Windows Workflow instance?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I have a windows workflow host with Persistence and Tracking services enabled. I would like to show my persisted/idling workflow instance as a Diagram (like in the visual studio workflow designer). Is there an easy way to do this?

Note that I would like to display this diagram in an Admin-like Web Interface that system administrators can use to view the state of a running workflow instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can rehost the designer. Not easy but doable. You could then colour/annotate the diagram's activities based on knowledge of workflow state via tracking. See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480213.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2007/09/17/using-the-ajax-workflow-monitor-with-net-3-5-beta-2.aspx) by Kirk Evans explains how to use an the Ajax Workflow Monitor to display the state of running instances on a web page. Looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link and then click on the download sample...That will include a workflow monitor already created for you with windows forms.

[Workflow Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742169%28VS.90%29.aspx)